# Need Solution regarding Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-templates

I have been going through Django-admin. but I am getting this error.
Here is **views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def Milton(request):
    print("This is a test page")
    return("<h1>Index</h1>")
```

urls.py

```
"""Medical URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from pathlib import Path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.views import Milton

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('Milton/', Milton.site.urls),
]
```

Here is the Powershell Command Line error:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ conda activate base
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (conda:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\milto\Desktop\Med\Medical> python -m venv .venv
PS C:\Users\milto\Desktop\Med\Medical> python .\manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 475, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 476, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 690, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 683, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\milto\Desktop\Med\Medical\Medical\urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from django.views import Milton
ImportError: cannot import name 'Milton' from 'django.views' (C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\views\__init__.py)
```

I have been going through this since I have made the changes.
I don't know what really happened here. But I need support regarding this. Please reply as soon as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the import `from django.views import Milton`. It needs to be  `from <app_name>.views import Milton`.